# Ruby Version Discrepancy when running server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.9, webrick

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10.3.0]
$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2010-09-28 13:45:50] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2010-09-28 13:45:50] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-08) [universal-darwin10.0]
[2010-09-28 13:45:50] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=20761 port=3000
```

When I check my version number, it looks like I'm running 1.9.2p0

But when I run the server, it shows that I'm running 1.8.7... Any ideas as to how I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two Ruby binaries. As well as two gem scripts and gem repos in your hdd. To find all the stuff you need - use the `which` command:

```
$ which -a ruby
$ which -a gem
```

Then just nuke the one you don't need and start using [rvm](http://rvm.io/).